# Unable to use the item value from FlatLists renderItem in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am pretty new to coding so really struggling with this but I'm sure it's something simple.

When using `Flatlist` `renderItem` `item`

```
_renderItem = ( item ) => {
    return (<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
        <Text>{GLOBAL.products[item].title}</Text>
    </View >)
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.list}>
            <FlatList
                data={[9,10]}
                renderItem={ this._renderItem} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

The `<Text>{item}</Text>` works fine and first renders 9 and then renders 10.

But the `<Text>{GLOBAL.products[item].title}</Text>` is giving me the error:

> TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_global.default.products[item].title

The `<Text>{GLOBAL.products[**{**item**}**].title}</Text>` doesn't work. and also the `_renderItem = ( **{**item**}** ) => {`.

The `<Text>{GLOBAL.products[9].title}</Text>` works fine. also have tried `GLOBAL.products[parseInt(item)].title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious you don't know about JavaScript Object and child calling. when you call a child but its parent does not exist, you definitely got an error also in the `Text` component of React Native you should pass at least an empty string.

You should develop the chaining calling of children defensively. for this, I offer you to read about [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and add it to your project by using [this link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining).

After installing you can write the `_renderItem` function like below:

```js
_renderItem = item => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text>{item}</Text>
    <Text>{GLOBAL?.products[item]?.title || ''}</Text>
  </View >
);
```

Or there is a better way to use [`lodash.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) by installing it with `yarn add lodash.get` or `npm install --save lodash.get`, and then use it like below:

```js
import get from 'lodash.get';

~~~

_renderItem = item => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text>{item}</Text>
    <Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', 'item', 'title'], '')}</Text>
  </View >
);
```

I prefer the second one. this defensive programming prevents your app from crashing.

Comment: i dont think this does what im looking, it renders the correct value for `<Text>{item}</Text>` but always returns an empty string for `<Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', 'item', 'title'], '')}</Text>`, why is this? i can use the value of item in the first text element but not in the second. this stops me getting an error but only because its using the default of `''` again, this works fine `<Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', '9', 'title'], '')}</Text>` and when `<Text>{item}</Text>` prints a 9,  `<Text>{get(GLOBAL, ['products', 'item', 'title'], '')}</Text>` still does not work

Comment: Dear @skylisk, your question is about the Error, your app crashes for the error of nested object chaining that has an `undefined` parent. so by using lodash `get` function your error disappear and your app doesn't crash. so it is the answer to this question. NOW, you have another question. _Why the `get(GLOBAL, ['products', '9', 'title'], '')` returns value but the `get(GLOBAL, ['products', 'item', 'title'], '')` does not. you can settle this question and ask another one with specific details. I hope to help you.

Comment: apologies, first ever post so maybe wasn't clear. will do!

Comment: No dude, @skylisk, there is no need to apologize, it is your question. ask again and again till find your answer.